# Unable to load library 'gs': libgs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, imagemagick, ghostscript, ghost4j

I have installed ghostscript of 64 bit on my 64 bit linux machine. I am using ghost4j-0.5.0.jar to convert pdf files to tiff files. I have written a java program which will convert pdf files to tiff files. This is working perfectly fine on Windows but when i thought of moving this to linux machine i am getting the below error.

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gs': libgs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I checked lib folder and could not find libgs.so file in the lib folder. I am not sure where to get that file.

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: It should be in the development package of ghostscript. The exact name of the package depends on your linux distribution. libgs-dev on debian derivatives, ghostscript-devel on Fedora, and probably something else on others

Answer (score 6):

I feel a little guilty posting this here since it is probably better served on ServerFault or one of the Linux boards and the question is over 6 months old but I had been banging my head against the wall all day and finally have found a solution to this problem and I figured someone else might benefit from this down the road.

Systems: `Windows 7` and `CentOS 6.5`

Using: `Ghostscript 9.14`

**A little backstory:**

Like the OP I had been running a ghostscript program on Windows to convert PDFs to a series of images. This worked fine until I needed to switch over to Linux and run the program and about 5% of the PDFs I needed to convert came up with `error cannot decode code stream`. I realized that I was using a **newer version** of ghostscript on Windows. (9.14 on Windows compared to 8.70 on CentOS due to installing through yum).

I removed the old version with `yum remove ghostscript`. Next, I found the easiest way to install the newest version of Ghostscript is download from [here](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) and compile. Since I removed the previous version of ghostscript with yum I had to update the link in `usr/bin` to point to `usr/local/bin/gs` with `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gs /usr/bin/gs`. With everything in place, so I thought, I attempted to run my program and then bam, error!

**Solving the problem:**

So now I was getting the error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gs': libgs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I came across a post [here](http://blog.snowfrog.net/2012/03/29/ghostscript-imagemagick-rhel-libgs-so-errors/) that said to get the necessary `libgs.so` I needed to go back and rebuild the source as a shared library with the command `make so`. I did so and then I took the `libgs.so.9.14` file under `sobin` directory in the ghostscript folder and copied it to `/usr/lib`. Under that directory I made a symbolic link to `libgs.so` using the command `ln -s /usr/lib/libgs.so.9.14 /usr/lib/libgs.so`.

Once that was done I needed to update my `ld_library_path` but found when I did so the change wasn't global so I found a [Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46614/how-to-export-ld-library-path-to-all-users-and-system-services) on how to set the global lib path. Basically to do so you need to go to add a `.conf` file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` with the path to the file. I did so using `vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libgs.conf` and added `/usr/lib/libgs.so` to the file. Lastly I ran `ldconfig` so save the changes.

TLDR:

1. [Download](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) the latest version of Ghostscript from source: `wget http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/ghostscript-9.14.tar.gz`
2. Unpack the tar: `tar -xzf  ghostscript-9.14.tar.gz`
3. `cd ghostscript-9.14`
4. `./configure`
5. `make` <-- You might be able to skip and go to `make so`, I did it in this order so I will leave it like this.
6. `make install`
7. `make so`
8. **If you removed a previous version with yum** `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gs /usr/bin/gs`
9. `cp ghostscript-9.14/sobin/libgs.so.9.14 /usr/lib`
10. `ln -s /usr/lib/libgs.so.9.14 /usr/lib/libgs.so`
11. `vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libgs.conf`
12. In the new libgs.conf file: `/usr/lib/libgs.so` and save with <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, `wq`.
13. `ldconfig` and done.
14. Run your conversion program.

Hopefully this helped and wasn't too confusing. I'm not a linux expert (yet) so I may be doing a little more work than necessary with the above commands but I wanted to be thorough.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issue on a linux VM. I was able to solve it by installing ghostscript on the system.  I just used the command:

```
sudo yum install ghostscript
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`make soinstall` will create required libs along with executables as mentioned in https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Install.htm#Shared_object